# Mysql get 1 value from duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

I made a query where I obtain duplicate values from a table `X`

```
id         | name    |     created         | modified 
­­­­­­­­­­­­-----------------------------------------------------------
 2         | Film1   | 2016-01-29 06:00:09 | 2016-01-29 06:00:10
 5         | Film1   | 2016-01-27 06:00:09 | 2016-01-27 06:00:10
 7         | Film1   | 2016-01-23 06:00:09 | 2016-01-23 06:00:10
 1         | Film2   | 2016-01-26 06:00:09 | 2016-01-26 06:00:10
 8         | Film2   | 2016-01-28 06:00:09 | 2016-01-28 06:00:10
 9         | Film2   | 2016-01-29 06:00:09 | 2016-01-29 06:00:10
```

I have a table `Y` where I obtain the number of photos of each duplicate value:

```
id         | name    |     num_photos      | 
­­­­­­­­­­­­--------------------------------------------
 2         | Film1   |        20           | 
 5         | Film1   |        10           | 
 7         | Film1   |        12           | 
 1         | Film2   |        20           | 
 8         | Film2   |        50           | 
 9         | Film2   |        12           |
```

How can I get the duplicated with more number of photos? IN a php array?

Result:

```
id         | name    |     num_photos | 
­­­­­­­­­­­­---------------------------------------
 2         | Film1   |        20      |  
 8         | Film2   |        50      |
```

Comment: **MAX(num_photos)** and **GROUP BY `name`** should help

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create table/insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE Y
    (`id` INT, `name` VARCHAR(5), `num_photos` INT)
;

INSERT INTO Y
    (`id`, `name`, `num_photos`)
VALUES
    (2, 'Film1', 20),
    (5, 'Film1', 10),
    (7, 'Film1', 12),
    (1, 'Film2', 20),
    (8, 'Film2', 50),
    (9, 'Film2', 12)
;
```

There are two ways off doing this.

With user variables.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   y.id
 , y.name
 , y.num_photos
FROM ( SELECT @name := '') AS init_user_var
CROSS JOIN (
 SELECT
  *
  , (y.name != @name) AS firstInGroup
  , @name := y.name
 FROM 
  Y
 ORDER BY 
    Y.name ASC
  , Y.num_photos DESC 
)
 AS
  Y   
WHERE
 y.firstInGroup = 1
ORDER BY 
 Y.id ASC
```

**Result**

```
    id  name    num_photos  
------  ------  ------------
     2  Film1             20
     8  Film2             50
```

With delivered table with max and group by and a join.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 y.*
FROM (
 SELECT 
   y.name 
  , MAX(y.num_photos) max_num_photos
 FROM 
  Y
 GROUP BY
  y.name 
) AS
 y_max_num_photos
INNER JOIN
  Y
ON
 Y.name = y_max_num_photos.name
 AND
 Y.num_photos = y_max_num_photos.max_num_photos
 ORDER BY 
  y.id ASC
```

**Result**

```
    id  name    num_photos  
------  ------  ------------
     2  Film1             20
     8  Film2             50
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be something like:

```
select * from (select * from y order by num_photos desc) sub group by name
```

Please adjust it a little by your needs.

Comment: SELECT * WITH GROUP BY name is not correct... https://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: so.. should he write the column names in place of *? will it change the answer direction ? ;)

Comment: This relies on an undocumented hack (unless you count the comments section of the manual), and should not be relied upon.

Answer (score -2):

Try below query.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(name) as name, (select max(num_photos) from Y) as num_photos, id FROM Y;
```

Comment: what about id? :)

Comment: @Anton What do you mean id?

Comment: @Anton happy now?

Comment: @JoshulSharma, Dont be mad, I haven't downvoted you, if you think so. But, what do you think he will get with your query? I think it will be the same row count as the table have, with the first field as max photos always, and this information doesnt tell anything related to what the author is asking for. Am i wrong?

Comment: @Anton not mad at you! its just your interpretation. :)